# Cant' fetch some information from a webpage using xhr

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to grab a certain portion of information from a webpage using `xmlhttp` request. When I execute my script, it throws an error `Object Variable Or With---`. But, when I try the same using `IE`, I get the content like magic.

The most important thing to notice is that the content I'm expecting to grab are neither javascript encrypted nor generated dynamically. So, I should get them using `xhr`. Where I'm going wrong?

***[Here goes the website link](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml)***

***Using `IE` (working one):***

```
Sub GetText()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With
    
    Set post = HTML.querySelectorAll(".section_content")(2)
    MsgBox post.innerText
End Sub
```

***Using XHR (not working):***

```
Sub GetText()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set post = HTML.querySelectorAll(".section_content")(2)
    MsgBox post.innerText
End Sub
```

The `selector` I've defined above is flawless.

I could have pasted here the relevant `html elements` but they are wrapped within `comments`. However, I've provided above the link to that site.

To be clearer: the portion of text I'm interested in looks exactly like below in that webpage.

[image]

> My question: how can I get the aforementioned textblock (which is shown above within image) using XHR?

Comment: I get exactly the same error with the IE version.
Try 
For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("section_content")
        MsgBox post.innerText
    Next

Comment: You get the same error using IE cause your `IE` version doesn't support `.querySelector()` @peakpeak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Using comment position:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        html.body.innerHTML = html.querySelector("#all_9711922514").LastChild.Data
        Debug.Print html.querySelector("#div_9711922514").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Method using nodeType:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, ele As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        For Each ele In html.querySelector("#all_9711922514").Children
            If ele.NodeType = 8 Then
                html.body.innerHTML = ele.Data
                Debug.Print html.querySelector("#div_9711922514").innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Method using regex:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Dim s As String
        s = .querySelector("div[id=all_1786105919]").outerHTML
        s = regexRemove(s, "<([^>]+)>")
        Debug.Print Replace$(Replace$(s, "&", "°"), "-->", vbNullString)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function regexRemove(ByVal s As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With

    If regex.test(s) Then
        regexRemove = regex.Replace(s, vbNullString)
    Else
        regexRemove = s
    End If
End Function
```

---

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Your solution should instantly be accepted. It's a very detailed one.

Comment: I prefer the simplicity of yours. I was just heading in that direction but you beat me to it! So I have had to dig for some other way of delivering a result  :sighs:

Answer (score 3):

The solution is plain and simple. All you need to do is kick out the `comment signs` from `responseText` using `Replace()` function or so and then filter them using `Html.body.innerHTML` to make them `proper html contents`. The rest is as usual.

This is how you can get the content:

```
Sub GetTextFromComment()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = Replace(Replace(.responseText, "<!--", ""), "-->", "")
    End With
    Set post = Html.querySelectorAll(".section_content")(2)
    MsgBox post.innerText
End Sub
```

Comment: Loving that solution.

Comment: Sweeet & Simple